# What do you call a person who checks people in to a food pantry

Tags: titles

I work at a food pantry and all clients must be registered per government regulations.  I either verify they are registered and check them off or help them fill out the required paperwork prior to distributing food.

Answer (score 2):

"**Food Pantry Assistant**" is probably the name of that occupation.

Here is a list of the duties of a food pantry assistant involved in a typical distribution center ([The Salvation Army](https://www.indeed.com/q-Food-Pantry-Assistant-jobs.html?vjk=9ae5b7580a8cd07a)).

Job Objective: To assist the Food Pantry Coordinator in all aspects of the Food Pantry.
Responsibilities:
This job description should not be interpreted as all inclusive. It is intended to identify the essential functions and requirements of the position. Other job related responsibilities and tasks may be assigned. Reasonable accommodation may be made to enable individuals with disabilities to perform the essential job functions.

- Assist Food Pantry Coordinator in maintaining food pantry inventory by coordinating the receipt of donations from drives and other community resources
- Assures that client information is recorded accurately in client records
- Maintain accurate statistical records as required
- Be familiar with current community resources to make appropriate referrals as needed and requested
- Assists individuals and families in the selection of items and packs food pantry orders according to family size
- Stocking shelves
- Assist in unloading food deliveries and sorting
- Review incoming food and existing inventory with regards to expiration dates, freshness, packaging damage, recalls, etc.
- Participate in seasonal social services activities as approved by Food Pantry Coordinator

Registering the clients must be a task that comes under the item "Assuring that client information is recorded accurately in client records" or possibly  "Maintaining accurate statistical records". As an assistant can't do all of that all the time, the specialized task you are talking about corresponds probably to this job title (food pantry assistant).